# Number of rays intersecting at a point inside a polygon

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, recreational-mathematics, billiards

I'm working on a project to do with bouncing rays inside polygons and now I've reached a crucial stage of this project in which I need help with and is related to the problem stated below. Your help will be highly appreciated.

$\\$

**Problem**

Let $P_n$ be a polygon such that if I shoot a ray from some point inside the polygon at a certain angle and I let the ray bounce off the edges continuously, I'll have at least one point $p$ *inside* the polygon with exactly $n$ rays (with different slopes) going through such point. We can refer to such polygon as a $P_n$-polygon. Does a $P_n$-polygon exist for every $n\geq 3?$ And if so, is such polygon also a $P_0, P_1,...,P_{n-1}$ polygon$?$

$\\$

(A square is an example of a $P_0,P_1$ and $P_2$-polygon depending on the position and the angle I shoot the ray from, inside the square.)

$\\$

UPDATE:
$\\$

Based on a comment below and after some tries, here's an example of a $P_0, P_1, P_2$ and $P_3$-Polygon.
[image]
[image]

In the first picture, if we choose $p$ as the starting point to shoot the ray from, inside the equilateral triangle, we can see that after the reflections the ray goes through $p$ from two different angles (slopes). The ray goes through point $q$, from only one angle (slope) and it never goes through $r$. As for the second picture we can see that using $s$ as the starting point, the ray goes through it from three different angles (slopes). Hence an equilateral triangle is an example of a $P_0, P_1, P_2$ and $P_3$-polygon.

$\\$
Whilst this is not a proof for the general case hopefully it should give some indication as to how to approach it.

Comment: How is a square an example of a $P_0$? What is your initial starting point, and which point can't you reach directly? In fact, I argue that given any starting point. every point can be reached via infinitely many reflections (this is obvious using the typical reflection grid setup), so a square is not a $P_n$ polygon for any $n$.

Comment: Different starting points and angles will give you different results. Suppose you shoot a ray from the centre of the square so that it's parallel to two of its edges. Then if you choose a point $p$ on the ray, then this ray will be the only one going through that point $p$. Since there is at least one point $p$ inside the square with exactly one ray (and no more) going through such point, the square is by definition a $P_1$-polygon.

Comment: Also in this scenario, any point not on this ray, will never be reached by this ray, since the ray will just keep on bouncing / reflecting  perpendicularly between the two eges. So the square also contains at least one point $q$ with no rays going through such point. So the square is also a $P_0$-polygon by definition.

Comment: By choosing a suitable starting point and angle to shoot the ray from - inside the square - you'll also have at least one point $r$ inside the square with exactly two rays (and no more) going through such point (after some reflections from the egdes of the square). Another way to put it is the ray will intersect itself at point $r$ exactly once inside the square. So again by definition the square is a $P_2$-polygon.

Comment: Finally notice that it doesn't matter how you choose your starting point and angle to shoot the ray from - inside the square - you can never get a point $s$ with exactly 3 (or more) rays going through $s$ (that is, two or more self-intersections at point $s$) .

Comment: Just consider the angles of the lines themselves. Since each reflection flips one of the coordinates of the direction of the line, there are only two different possible slopes; the odd-reflected one and the even-reflected one. So any intersection must be between two segments of these two different slopes, and there's no 'third angle' a line could come in from. Hence the square is not a $P_n$-polygon for any $n > 2$

Comment: The main thing to remember here is that when we talk about rays going through a point $p$, we mean rays with different slopes going through $p$.

Comment: In a square why not for each point there are infinite rays that can go through?

Comment: In a square for each point there are at least four rays with different slopes that go through... or may be I am not following what you are attempting. Two perpendicular to the sides and two at $45^0$

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding here. But I'll clarify it further.

Comment: STEP 1: You choose 'one' starting point and 'one' angle inside the square to shoot the ray from.

Comment: STEP 2: You let this same 'one' ray reflect off the edges of the square continuously (infinitely many times).

Comment: STEP 3:  Check if there is a point inside the square with no ray going through it, and a point inside the square with the 
ray (with one slope only) going through it, and a point inside the square with the ray going through it 
(with two different slopes) and so on...

Comment: STEP 4: Choose another starting point and/or angle, repeat steps 2 and 3 and see if you can get any different 
behaviour from before.

Comment: Each different behaviour from these reflections inside the square determines exactly one type of polygon.

Comment: Taking a quick look at the comments, I believe the confusion arises from "ray" having double usage. As such, to clarify, I believe what you want is "Choose an initial starting point. Chooset 1 ray. Trace out the infinite path it takes. Choose a given point. If there are $n$ distinct lines through it, then this is a $P_n$."

Comment: Yes. That's the idea.

Comment: For a similar reason of angle chasing, with an equilateral triangle, initial point the center, given point the center, it is a $P_0$, $P_1$ (if we allow for the ray to pass through a vertex with the "natural" reflection across the angle bisector), and a $P_3$. However, it cannot be a $P_2$, so the answer to the latter question is "no".

Comment: That's an interesting result. Thanks for the update. It would be interesting to see the picture for $P_3$

Comment: Could you tell me what initial angle you used at the centre (as the initial point) to get $P_3$ at the centre (as the given point)? Also could you tell me why $P_2$ doesn't work?

Comment: Your notation is confusing, since the set you name $P_n$ is not independent of starting point $x$ and ray angle $\alpha$. I suggest a change of notation, e.g. $(P,\,x,\,\alpha) \in E_n$ means $\exists y \in P$, such that ray starting at $x$ with angle $\alpha$ goes through $y$ with $n$ different angles.